# Git - Contraseña

Tags: git, gitlab

Buenos días comunidad!

Estoy teniendo un problema en Git, resulta que yo cambie mi contraseña en GitLab y ahora en mi repositorio local no puedo hacer push debido a que me tira el siguiente error:

```
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied. The provided password or token is incorrect or your account has 2FA enabled and you must use a personal access token instead of a password.

fatal: Authentication failed for
```

Como puedo ingresar mi nueva contraseña?

Gracias!

Comment: ¿Qué sistema operativo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proba con la siguiente:

1. En la caja de busqueda de Windows escribe "administrador de credenciales" y luego selecciona "Credenciales de Windows".
2. Editar la entrada de git o GitLab en Credenciales de Windows y reemplazar la contraseña anterior por la nueva.
3. Por las dudas reinicia tu laptop o pc para que se registren los cambios en windows.
4. Ya prodrias hacer push normalmente.